# Watson Studio Translator API credentials for jypter notebook

Tags: watson, watson-studio

I'm trying to follow a tutorial, learn some more about calling APIs from a notebook. Seems the tutorial directions are no longer aligned with the bluemix platform as I'm supposed to provision a translator service, then pull my username and password from the credentials. As the only credentials created look like the below credentials, can someone please tell me how I find the username and password?

```
{
  "apikey": "uK7Wv6hfKjTO_p56lhzZy302QmTZCyPI_FYFkqMLGOS0",
  "iam_apikey_description": "Auto generated apikey during resource-key operation for Instance - crn:v1:bluemix:public:language-translator:us-south:a/bff2d8201267d05e8b5580a56638c7a0:5eb84a08-7dd1-4a12-8385-b1eb043e1fcc::",
  "iam_apikey_name": "auto-generated-apikey-eb2957a2-f849-4f89-a830-2f6d688ec4a9",
  "iam_role_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::serviceRole:Manager",
  "iam_serviceid_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam-identity::a/bff2d8201267d05e8b5580a56638c7a0::serviceid:ServiceId-2588fac4-f9ea-4461-8e6c-be358855f9c7",
  "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed these instructions:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/language-translator/api/v3/curl.html
ibm.com  ?  If you can share your tutorial that might also help. (Also, your question exposed your api key; I recommend deleting it and making a new one.)

Here's an example curl call:

`curl --user apikey:{apikey} "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v3/identifiable_languages?version=2018-05-01"`

where the username is apikey and the password is the actual api key (for curl).  This may also be helpful: 
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/language-translator/getting-started.html#gettingstarted